# Weird Android program error

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

This code is giving an error saying "error receiving broadcast intent in activity"
I cant find any eroors though...........any ideas ?
i've added the loop condition as seven as i only want the first seven scan results

```
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context con, Intent intent) {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();

        for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
        {
            sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).SSID.toString());
            sb.append(' ');
            sb.append('!');
            sb.append("\n\n");
        }

        String net = sb.toString();

        if(wifiList.size() > 0)
        {


        char excl = '!';
        int excl1 = excl;
        String[] aray = null;
        for(int j = 0; j<7; j++)
        {
            int index = net.indexOf(excl1);
            String a = net.substring(0, index);
            aray[j] = a;
            String temp = net.substring(index+1);
            net = temp;

        }

        String one = aray[0];
        String two = aray[1];
        String three = aray[2];
        String four = aray[3];
        String five = aray[4];
        String six = aray[5];
        String seven = aray[7];
        tv1.setText(one);

    }
        else
        {
            tv1.setText("No Networks Detected");
        }
}
}
```

PS : I've only added into one TextView as this is a test module

Comment: have you declared the BroadcastReceiver in your android manifest?

Comment: Have to stepped through this code?  Is it throwing a runtime error such as a list index out of bounds or a null exception?

Comment: It says RuntimeError: Error Receiving broadcastIntent

Comment: @Neal Caffrey, Is that the entire error message?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS }

Comment: Post the stack trace from the NullPointerException. Probably `mainWifi` is null or `mainWifi.getScanResults()` is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "aray" array is not being intialized correctly.  You need to initialize "aray" before accessing it:

```
String[] aray = new String[7];
```

You are also going outside the dimensions of the array. this:

```
String seven = aray[7];
```

should be:

```
String seven = aray[6];
```

An even better solution would be to use an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add(yourString);
```

Comment: Its not an assigning problem because if I remove the if-else condition and directly assign String net to the TextView it works. What else could i do